# Kotlin object init blocked by join on Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, object, kotlin

I am writing an Android app in Kotlin, which is going to be a client to a server developed by my group. I wanted to create an object `Connection` that would store all necessary data about a socket connection to a server:

```
object Connection {
    const val HOST = "host_name" // in project it is well defined
    const val PORT = 52137
    const val TIMEOUT = 5000

    val socket: Socket = Socket()

    /* ... */

    val connectData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val errorData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        val connect = Thread({
            val address = InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT)
            socket.connect(address, TIMEOUT)
        })
        connect.uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler({ t, e ->
            e.printStackTrace()
        })
        connect.start()
        connect.join()
        /*
        some more data processing
        */
    }
    /*
    some functions
    */
}
```

I use `join()` so that I can get my socket fully initialized. However, when I create a main activity in my application, the initialization of this object gets stuck on `connect.join()`. Here's the code:

```
class LoginActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        Connection.connectData.observe(this, Observer(this::displayConnectData))
        Connection.errorData.observe(this, Observer(this::displayError))

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        login_button.setOnClickListener({
            val loggedIn = viewModel.login(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
            if (loggedIn) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        })
    }


    private fun displayConnectData(message: String?) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun displayError(message: String?) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

I know that objects in Kotlin are lazily initialized, so the Connection object starts initializing when `Connection.connectData.observe(this, Observer(this::displayConnectData))` is called, but I don't know why it gets stuck on `connect.join()` despite defining the timeout on connect. Can I fix this problem easily or should I take different approach with this object?

Comment: Isn't this approach flawed even if it worked? You're not allowed to block the UI thread like that and let your whole application completely freeze for the duration of connection establishment, which can easily take seconds.

Comment: Keep your networking stuff on background threads and don't "synchronously wait" for them